# Using SAS to insert records into DB2 database

Tags: db2, sas

To give a background, I am using 
- base SAS in mainframe (executed by JCL) and 
- DB2 as the database.

I have the list of keys to read DB in a mainframe dataset. I understood that we can join a sas dataset with a DB2 table to read as follows.

```
%LET DSN=DSN;
%LET QLF=QUALIFIER;
PROC SQL;
     CONNECT TO DB2(SSID=&DSN);
     CREATE TABLE STAFFTBL AS
            (SELECT * FROM SASDSET FLE,
                           CONNECTION TO DB2
                                (SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
                                   FROM &QLF..TABLE_NAME)
                                 AS DB2 (COL1, COL2, COL3)
             WHERE DB2.COL1 = FLE.COL1);
     DISCONNET FROM DB2;
     %PUT &SQLXMSG;
QUIT;
```

can someone suggest me, if I have a dataset with list of values to be inserted in a mainframe dataset, how should we proceed.

We can read the mainframe dataset and get the values in a SAS dataset. But I am not able to guess on how to use the sas dataset to insert values to DB2.

I know we can do it using COBOL. But I am willing to learn if it is possible using SAS.

Thanks!

Solution:
Have to assign library to write to DB. Please refer to the SAS Manual [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hosto390/61886/HTML/default/viewer.htm#mvs-stmt-libname.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your above query creates a local SAS dataset in the Work library or wherever your default library is declared. This table is **not** connected to your backend DB2 database but simply a copy used as import into SAS.

Consider establishing a live connection using an ODBC SAS library. If not ODBC, use the DB2 API SAS has installed. Once connected all tables in specified database will emerge as available SAS datasets in a SAS library and these are not imported copies but *live* tables. Then run any `proc sql` append or use `proc.append` to insert records to table from SAS.

Below are generic examples with DSN or non-DSN which you can modify according to your credentials or database driver type.

```
* WITH DSN;
libname DBdata odbc datasrc="DSN Name" user="username" password="password";

* WITH DRIVER (NON-DSN) - CHECK DRIVER INSTALLATION;
libname DBdata odbc complete="driver=DB2 Driver; Server=servername;
                              user=username; pwd=password; database=databasename;";
```

Append procedures:

```
* WITH SQL;
proc sql;
      INSERT INTO DBdata.tableName (col1, col2, col3) 
      SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM SASDATASET;
quit;

* WITH APPEND (ASSUMING COLUMNS MATCH TOGETHER);
proc datasets;
    append base = DBdata.tableName
    data = SASDATASET
    force;
quit;
```

**NOTE:** Be very careful not to unintentionally add, modify, or delete any table in the SAS ODBC library as these datasets are live tables, so such changes *will* reflect in backend DB2 database. When finished with work, do not delete the library (or all tables will be cleaned out), simply unassign it from environment:

```
libname DBdata clear;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I edited my question to point to SAS manual for more reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have the necessary write access, you should be to do this via a proc sql `insert into` statement. Alternatively, if you can access the db2 table via a library, it may be possible to use a data step with both a `modify` and an `output` / `replace` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have write access to the DB and can insert data one by one using ` INSERT into ` statement. All I am expecting is a way to use sas datasets directly as input. Something like `INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM SASDATASET`.

Comment: Have a look at the bottom example [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/62086/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001387930.htm)

Comment: I checked the example. Thanks for sharing it. If you note properly, both the tables used are SQL tables and hence it is possible. Moreover my question is on how to join  a sasdataset with DB2 table in mainframe environment. Hence I gave an example in my initial question itself (with select query). It is not straight forward as the example given there in mainframe environment. It will be something like `CONNECT TO DB2(SSID=&DSN) EXECUTE (INSERT INTO TABLE (   ) VALUES (  )) BY DB2;` and the SASDATASET cannot be joined directly after connecting to DB2.